# Only allowing user to send input once, MeteorJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, meteor

I am working on an app where users can book courses, and I want every users to only be able to cook a course once. Here is the code that I have now, hope that you guys will help me :)

```
 'click #book': function(e,tmpl){
  if($.inArray(Session.get('userID'), Courses.find({_id: this._id}, {fields:{attendees: 1}})) === -1){
    console.log('You have already booked this course');
  }else{
    Courses.update(this._id, {$push: {attendees: Session.get('userID')}});
    Courses.update(this._id, {$inc: {numberPlaces: -1}});
    console.log('You have booked the course');
  }
```

}

As you can see I record the user's Id in the collection and check if his id already exists in there whenever he tries to book a course.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the context in your event handler is a course document, then you can just do this:

```
if (_.contains(this.attendees, Meteor.userid()))
  console.log('Already booked!');
```

Otherwise, you can do the check right in the selector:

```
if (Courses.findOne({_id: this._id, attendees: Meteor.userid()}))
  console.log('Already booked!');
```

Replace Meteor.userid() with your session variable if that actually refers to a different user.